# Copy only files starting with s to a directory and create a new file with all the content of the copied files. Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to copy all the files starting with s from the directory `/etc` to my directory `/root`.
Then I would like to create a new file in my directory `/root` named resume, with all the content of the copied files.
Finally I want to delete all the files I have copied in my directory `/root` (don't want to delete anything from `/etc`).

This is my code

```
for i in $(find /etc/s* -type f);do
   echo $i
   cp $i -vi /root
   $i > /root/resume
done
```

I haven´t find the way to delete the files copied from `/etc` after creating resume.
Also when I run the code then I look into my directory and some files do not start with letter "s".
I believe cp is copying files which subdirectory starts with "s" even though the file doesn't.
I want to ignore subdirectories.

Comment: but.... `cp /etc/s* /root`? `delete the files copied from /etc after creating resume` Really, like `rm /etc/s*`? `and some files do not start with letter "s".` `find` finds files _recursively_, so if you have a dir `/etc/sdir` it will find files not starting with s there. You want to find files starting with s recursively or only in /etc/ ?

Comment: Gratuitously removing files from `/etc` by a script seems like a **REALLY BAD IDEA** (TM)

Comment: If all the files are in a single directory just do `cat s* > newfile` -- but I wouldn't clutter `/root`. If running as `root` create `/root/tmp` and then `cat /etc/s* > /root/tmp/resume` Keep `/root` clean.

Comment: It would be like rm /root/s* because I want to delete the files I have just copied, after creating /root/resume. I know it does not have much sense but it is what I have been asked to do.

Comment: ??? `/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/services`, ...: are you deleting all those files?

Comment: I dont want to delete anything from /etc, I want to delete from /root. With rm /root/s* I can delete files that were not copied from /etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `find` command also catches files with arbitrary names, which are located in a subdirectory of /etc, as long as the name of the subdirectory starts with s. For instance, it would catch all files in /etc/setup.

You would find all the files in /etc by

```
for i in /etc/s*
do
  ....
done
```

Of course the operations you seem to do on the files are highly questionable (for instance, you try to execute them, without checking whether they are executable). Deleting them from `root` can be done by `rm "/root/${i#*/}"`.

Comment: Thank you! How would it be if I want all the files starting with s (no matter the subdirectory it`s in and the name of that subdirectory).

Comment: @agm_s502 : Since this is now a new problem, please ask a new question on Stackoverflow. The idea of SO is that we have one question in one posting. Since it is not exactly clear to me what you want to achieve, make sure that you provide a suitable example (along with your own attempt to solve the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of playing around with system files in the /etc dir, but the below should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp /etc/s* /root

cat /root/s* > /root/resume

rm /root/s*
```

Comment: Sorry if I explained myself wrong, I dont want to remove anything from etc. I would like to remove from /root all the files copied. I thought in /root/s* but I can remove some file that weren´t copied from /etc.